# TYPO3 - nested gridelements

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, tx-gridelements

I'd like to get a solution for the TYPO3 EXT:gridelements.

I need gridelements in gridelements (nested) for Bootstrap Tab´s:

- Grid Container Outer

  - Grid Container 1

    - Text with Image
    - Text
    - Text with Image
  - Grid Container 2

    - Text
    - Text with Image

with a foreach-loop (debug) it works for output from the grid-containers, but it renders Grid Container 1 and Grid Container 2 together in one gridelements col.

I need the output separated and would appreciate any help.

Comment: please specify your versions and provide your configuration.

Comment: I usually solve this with a custom template element. If you have fixed amount of infos, you can use simple fields to fill in the data you need. if you have custom amount of infos, you can use `flux:form.object` https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/flux/master/Form/ObjectViewHelper.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `TypoScript` file you've probably to set the proper path to the `gridelement` template:

```
tt_content.gridelements_pi1.20.10.setup {
    TwoColumns < lib.gridelements.defaultGridSetup
    TwoColumns {
    cObject = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    cObject {
        file = Ext:path/to_your/template/template_name.html
    }
}
```

The template file can look somehow like this:

```
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <f:format.raw>{data.tx_gridelements_view_column_11}</f:format.raw>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
    <f:format.raw>{data.tx_gridelements_view_column_12}</f:format.raw>
   </div>

  </div>
```

And make sure your grid columns `colPos` parameter are equal to `tx_gridelements_view_column_...` in the template.